Is the answer: enough time?
Are there probability calculations about when a given gene mutation turns out to be an advantage rather than a disadvantage for the respective individual and then proves to be an evolutionary advantage over generations?

Probability hurdle: It takes ? x generations for a mutation to actually turn out to be an individual reproductive advantage. How much higher is the chance that the embryo is already stunted?

Probability hurdle: At the same time, numerous other individuals in the respective ecological niche also mutate, which may bring them other, but even better advantages. They win the reproductive competition, the first mutation perishes even though it was good.

Probability hurdle: even if the mutation is an advantage (e.g. light-sensitive cells, feathers, lactose tolerance), a mistake can wipe out the respective individual. Or the habitat changes too quickly. Or invasive species conquer the previously successfully occupied niche in the system. Or other parallel mutations are counterproductive. The mutation dies even though it was good.


Is the anser: there was enough time?
Are there algorithms that can capture all of this? Or AI-based simulation models?

Welcome semco543. We can't know what the answer may be unless you ask an actual question. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [ask] section of the [help], then [edit] to clarify what you're asking. Remember, one clearly focused question per post. (Though, what you've stated in your 3 postulates is quite right broadly)

You are treating mutations like they are all the same. Look at Covid for e.g., you can change some parts of the spike gene more or less with impunity and get more or less fit, but some other parts are impossible to change and produce viable virus. You would need probability calcs for each individual possible mutation...

As a new user of this site, please do us the courtesy of finishing the [Tour] (we know you haven’t.) And pay us the respect of providing a title that reflects your question so that users can judge whether it is of interest to them, indexing will be useful.

I think the keyword you are looking for further reading might be "fixation": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixation_(population_genetics) which is the process of one allele becoming the only allele in a population. It is possible to study fixation both of neutral variations and non-neutral variations that have some influence of selection.
Do not expect some simple equation or "AI model", though, especially in the variable circumstances you describe where fitness is a function of frequency.
